# Why does MariaDB 10.1.16 vanilla installation comes with an almost empty config file?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.1

Why does MariaDB 10.1.16 vanilla installation comes with an almost empty config file (/etc/my.cnf) ? Whereas it is not the case for MySQL. The config file for MySQL is usually not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it answers your question, but in /etc/my.cnf:

```
#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

One of the files in this directory is:

```
mariadb-server.cnf
```

This file and possibly other files as well does not exists in MySQL.